# Mushroom Identification

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I live in central Ohio and found these mushrooms growing on our 10 acre property. What is it and are they edible?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any picture showing the size? And especially the underside of the umbrella?

Comment: In addition to showing the underside of the umbrella, it would also probably be helpful to be more specific about the property, and where on the property they were found. In the middle of a lawn? On some mulch? By a tree or stump? Clustered together?